# Can I save a "star-hash" (*#) code as contact?

Tags: contacts, huawei, logging, dialer-codes

I'm developing on a Huawei phone, and to enable logging on this device one must dial `*#*#2846579#*#*` to get to a hidden service menu, as described in [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43557441/930640).

Is there any way I can save this code as a contact and "dial" it from the favourites list for easy access? Of course I tried just adding a new contact with the code as the number, but when I "dial" it the phone actually dials the number instead of opening the hidden service menu, resulting in a "Sorry, you can't dial this number" voice message from my phone operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is *not* meant to be dialled as an ordinary contact number

Quoting from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9947615) answer

> What the dialer really does when you enter the code is **extracting** the number between *#*# and #*#* and then broadcasting the following intent....

Saving it as a contact and trying to dial means it is a treated as a regular, valid number

- Which is rejected by the service provider , since it is not a valid number
- Expected code is not launched since the corresponding intent is not triggered

You can try creating a shortcut to the intent using an apps like Tasker