# How to quickly factory reset an Android phone

Tags: applications, factory-reset

Let us assume I am working/living in a potentially hostile environment and want to minimize the risk that somebody can access the data stored on my Android phone. The recommended way is to force-lock the phone to ensure that it cannot be accessed without the password, but this does not fully protect against data extractions applied directly on the phone. And going through the multi-step approach of resetting the phone via Settings is obviously not feasible under pressure.

So I am looking for ways to quickly factory reset on an Android phone. Something like "press one icon, confirm with one button = reset Android phone to factory settings".. with no passwords, no PINs... just quick wipe.

How can I accomplish this?

PS: I am aware that this may also lead to unexpected data loss in case the function is triggered by mistake. That is a risk I am willing to take.

Comment: This [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=au.dja.screenlock.activities) was quoted in a [different context](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/255416/how-to-force-factory-reset-with-low-battery-samsung-galaxy-s21)

Comment: Be aware that features like [Samsung Knox](https://docs.samsungknox.com/admin/fundamentals/whitepaper/appendix/knox-certifications/#:~:text=The%20Knox%20Platform%20has%20successfully,a%20trusted%20mobile%20security%20solution.) are targeting governments & organizations concerned about their data at rest on mobile devices. Also realize that 'one button wipe' in the age of phone theft means that some authorization is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each OEM (and likely individual model) will have their own custom MMI codes, which IMO would be among the fastest methods.  For example, here's the applicable codes for OnePlus 8T+ 5G:

**[Reset Your OnePlus Device](https://oneplus.gadgethacks.com/how-to/100-secret-dialer-codes-for-oneplus-phones-0185738/)**

> OnePlus lets you instantly wipe all data and restore your device to factory settings by inputting a variety of dialer codes, depending on how much information you want to preserve. For instance, you can enter *#*#7780#*#* to remove your Google account and all the apps you've installed, along with all data associated with them, but keep all other files like photos and other media files.
>
> *#8778# ...............Resets device, can be canceled
> *#*#7780#*#* ..........Erases Google account, third-party apps, & all associated data. Can be canceled
> *#*#947322243#*#* .....Instant Data Wipe, BEWARE!!! Get out by booting into fastboot
> *2767*3855# ...........Completely wipes device & reinstalls firmware
>
> Be careful of what code you input however, as *#*#947322243#*#* will instantly reboot your device in preparation for a factory data wipe and reset, as opposed to *#8778# and *#*#7780#*#* that can be easily canceled by hitting the back button.

This can be saved as a contact, then added to home screen as a widget.  In my experience, it may not directly launch when invoked as a contact, so you may have to omit, e.g., the last asterick and manually input it instead, etc.  This can likely be circumvented using some other automation tool, e.g., MacroDroid, etc., to implement a true one-touch solution.

Comment: See here as to why  [codes can't be saved as contacts](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/191202/131553)

Answer (score 0):

There are many apps that will remotely wipe the data from your phone.  I am using Kaspersky (for many things).  Some of the features, on theft, is to locate teh device, lock the device, take a mugshot, wipe data...

But I have used [Wheres my droid](https://www.wheresmydroid.com/features.html) in the past.  One of the many features is  to wipe personal data when the phone is stolen.

[image]

Wipe
Remove all personal data from the device.